# Help diagnosing a GFCI that instantly trips. Did I nick a wire with a screw?

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

I noticed that there were no GFCI outlets in the kitchen of my house and decided to add some. I installed one at the outlet closest to the sink but when I turned the power back on the GFCI tripped instantly. I checked the wiring and it was good. I replaced the GFCI receptacle for another new one and had the same issue. I disconnected the load side of the receptacle and the issue went away telling me that there was a problem downstream of the outlet.

I put the non-GFCI outlet back in by the sink and moved the GFCI outlet to the next receptacle downstream. The results were exactly the same. I kept moving the GFCI downstream until the GFCI wouldn't trip when I turned the power back on.

Between the last place the GFCI trips and the first place it doesn't, I had installed some shelves a while back. There were no problems when I did it. I figure now that if I had hit a wire, it would've been pretty dramatic. I drilled a small hole in the drywall to snake in a camera, but it's an outside wall and there was too much insulation to see anything.

[image]

I can't think of anything else to test, but it's hard for me to believe I hit a wire and didn't know about it. I'm hesitant to open up the wall so I'm hoping somebody has an idea as to what else might be the cause.

Comment: Usually hitting a wire with a nail/screw is not that exciting.  Touching that nail with your other hand grounded can be.  If you drove a nail in, most likely it is not between the hot and ground, instant breaker trip.

Comment: Could try a GFCI just before the shelves again, but only put hot/neutral on the load.  Don't attach ground.   If it doesn't trip, indicates the ground is part of the problem (rather than it leaking through a random other wire or pipe or something).

Comment: Are there any red wires in the receptacle circuit? Do you have to turn off 2 breakers or a double breaker to de-energize the circuit?

Answer (score 0):

Since the GFCI is tripping in the next-to-last position, it seems to think there is some leakage.

With the power off, and the downstream from that position disconnected, I might put multimeter on the downstream wire at that point (especially between hot and ground) and see if it reads anything other than completely open.  If it shows a resistance, you know there's a real problem with the wiring.

Or, could try GFCI there without the downstream ground connected to anything (just to see if it insta-trips, not permanently).  If it doesn't trip, then the leakage is happening through that conductor and not some other random path.

Any chance the run is straight enough that the wires could be pulled without opening up?  Might be able to pull a new segment if so.

Could also put in 4 GFCI outlets, with that segment not connected to any of the loads. But I'd probably worry about why that segment is tripping.

Comment: "Or, could try GFCI there without the downstream ground connected to anything (just to see if it insta-trips, not permanently). If it doesn't trip, then the leakage is happening through that conductor and not some other random path."

Just tried it, still trips.

I don't have a multimeter atm or I'd try to test resistance.

Comment: Hmm then whatever leakage it finds is not through the ground, but something else.  That's pretty odd, and would be harder to test with a meter. Any chance of pulling the wire?